# How to plot the CMB power spectrum?

Tags: cosmology, cosmic-microwave-background

It's possible to get the power spectrum of the CMB from the Lambda CDM model. But how do I get this plot? I'd like to mainpulate the parameters like it's possible in this "ancient" tool https://map.gsfc.nasa.gov/resources/camb_tool/index.html.
The team of the Planck spacecraft calculated the parameters by fitting the theoretical curve to their data but how is this theoretical curve calculated from the model?

Comment: [How to calculate the CMB spectrum](https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0606683)

Comment: Thank you very much, turns out it's sometimes it would be easier to just google things. In the meantime I found some 20 years old FORTRAN code called 'cmbfast', which does what I want it to do but without the theory. Now I have both.

Comment: CAMB is not an ancient tool! It's still actively developed and used by the community, along with a competitor in C called CLASS. Both of these will do a better job for you than CMBFAST and have easy to use python wrappers: https://camb.info/, https://lesgourg.github.io/class_public/class.html.

Comment: Well CAMB is not ancient and thanks to your comment I am using it now. But the tool on the NASA website is 'ancient' enough to be disabled since tuesday because it uses flash.

Comment: https://chrisnorth.github.io/planckapps/Simulator/ does part of what you want, but it doesn't show the measured power spectrum so it's not a perfect match to the NASA WMAP tool